# Recyclerview without Scrolling, but still showing all my Items

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-listview, itemtouchhelper

Situation:

Currently I have multiple RecyclerViews with each different Categories of Items in a ScrollView. My Plan is to have multiple Lists of Items displayed from multiple ArrayLists in Lists, where I can delete certain Items by swiping right/ left on them.
All these Lists are supposed to be on one Page.
So I can Scroll through these Lists, but swipe right/ left on Items I dont want.

My Problem with the RecyclerView is that it has it's own Scroll function... which of course makes sense. Thats the whole point behind it. Yet I haven't found a way to swipe right / left on Items without using RecyclerViews (/ ItemTouchHelper).
So I tried it anyway... turning off the RecyclerView Scroll function, but I then didn't get a list of 20 Items anymore. My list was reduced to 9 Items.
My guess is that all the other Items are there, but can't be uncovered, because the Scroll function is off.
So my List is reduced to all Items that fit onto my Screen without Scrolling

Question:

1. Is there a way to use a ListView or something like that, where the swipe function- right / left so I can remove Items from that List exists?
2. Is there a way to still use the RecyclerView but have all Items of my List displayed. Meaning the RecyclerView would get Characteristics of a ListView

I need:

I need the Swipe to be instant, like with the RecyclerView. I want to swipe the Item and it instantly needs to go. I don't want / like to swpie and then getting a side menu that asks me whether I want to delete this Item. The Swipe needs to be instant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `ListView` scrolls, so I do not see how it would help you. Perhaps you could try [this library](https://github.com/zerobranch/SwipeLayout) for a general-purpose swipe container that would work for swipe-to-delete and is not tied to `RecyclerView`. There are [many other libraries that offer "swipe" behavior](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=swipe), though it is unclear which of them might match your desired UX, and many of those are not designed for your scenario.

Comment: I have checked a couple of Libraries, but they seem to all have something I dont want / like. 
I need the swipe to be instant. I don't want a menu pop up on the side, where you then have to click delete or something like that

Comment: [The one that I linked to](https://github.com/zerobranch/SwipeLayout) seems to offer that (see Item 2 and Item 3 in the animation at the top of the README, and I think `app:isContinuousSwipe` is the attribute that controls this behavior). Beyond that, these libraries are open source, so you could look at their implementations.

Comment: Have you found any reason not to use [Google's ConcatAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter) instead of a `ScrollView`?